# CURL certificate issue. Chrome disagrees

Tags: web-services, ssl, curl, certificate, asmx

I am trying to access a webservice.
Before when I was trying to run that webservice in my Chrome web browser, I was getting 403 error but when I imported Private.pfx file into chrome certificates, I could easily access the webservice.

Now with curl I am getting 403 forbidden error. 
I followed this link
[using-certificates-with-curl](http://www.rajatswarup.com/blog/2007/03/10/using-certificates-with-curl/)

```
1) Convert it into PEM format (X.509 certificate) using openssl.
openssl pkcs12 -in abcd.pfx -out abcd.pem
Enter a passphrase and a password.
2) Still you cannot use this with curl because you’d get a few errors.
3) Convert this PEM certificate into three different certificates for the client, the private key and the certification authority certificate.
openssl pkcs12 -in abcd.pfx -out ca.pem -cacerts -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in abcd.pfx -out client.pem -clcerts -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in abcd.pfx -out key.pem -nocerts
4) Use the following command:
curl -k https://www.thesitetoauthenticate.com/test -v –key key.pem –cacert ca.pem –cert client.pem:
```

and made 3 certificates out of my Private.pfx file and try to run the command but I still get 403 error

Also webservice is accessible via this example link:

```
https://example:10443/soaplistener/eurisczech.asmx
```

This is my curl request:

```
curl -key key.pem -cacert ca.pem -cert client.pem -v -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -d @completeRequest.xml https://example:10443/soaplistener/eurisczech.asmx -ik
```

Comment: A HTTP 403 response is *not* a certificate problem!

Comment: @DanielStenberg could be a problem if requiring client certificate is set as optional. User could reject to present one, the SSL connection is stablished but the backend server is expecting a certificate and return an error. There are reasons to do this, but in 90℅ is a configuration error

Comment: No, a 403 implies that the TLS layer is fine == no cert issues. The problem is then on the HTTP layer.

Comment: yes, HTTP layer. I refer to an expected client certificate after TLS. It is the unique cause I can think because it worked after installing client certificates in chrome